# ajax call don't wait until response(long request). IE 11

Tags: ajax, request, internet-explorer-11, uploadify

I have a WebService called by ajax, the first one has method that takes a long process to return the response.

1- I set a request timeout in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" />
```

2- I added cache:false in the ajax request.

3- Added Error aswell to catch if something went wrong during the request. ( XMLHttpRequest returns "error" but the proces already finished )

Notes:

1- I'm using uploadify script and doing the ajax call into the step "oncomplete". ( after uploading a file )
2- If I upload a lightweight file the process goes well.

Any idea? Thanks a lot for your support